# Distribution of discrete, integer-valued Scores for Missing data imputation

Tags: multiple-imputation

In studies of aging, physical performance is assessed using instruments where the result is scored as a discrete integer variable that ranges from 0 to K.  For example, a commonly used assessment tool is Short physical performance battery (SPPB), in which the integer score ranges from 0 to 12, with 0 being unable to perform the test and 12 being the best performance. Typically, the data is left skewed with most people scoring in the high range of 10 to 12.  I would like to ask how to model this data, i.e. what type of probability distributions would be appropriate for this type of data.  My primary goal is to impute values for missing SPPB scores.